# SVG: <use> element not working when nested in g (with fiddle!)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, sprite

I need to display use elements in my SVG graphic.

When I try to use them from within a g element it doesn't work. 
In a little demo it looks like the use element works outside of g elements.

Here the fiddle (you can scroll down to the use elements to see the demo):

http://jsfiddle.net/3dacnxdb/2/

Why is it like this? How can i display them from within a g element? 
(My graphic is made out of many modules I need the gs to seperate them)

I appreciate any help!

```html
<svg id="graphic">
  <defs>

    <clipPath id="icon-cp">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="150" height="100" />
    </clipPath>

    <image id="icon-sprite" width="969" height="293"
    xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPx5h.png" />

    <g id="icon2" clip-path="url(#icon-cp)">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-sprite" transform="translate(-240,0)" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <!--     ----------------------------------------
    Here is the question:
    
    the first use element is not displayed.
    The second one is displayed. (the elements are under this text)
    
    Why does it not work? 
    How can a use element be used within nested g elements?

    (to test it you can comment out the second use element, 
    even tough both use elements have the same attributes 
    no icon is visible anymore)
    ---------------------------------------- -->

  <!--  following does not work: -->
  <g id="testg">
    <use xlink:href="#icon2" x="100" y="50" />
  </g>

  <!--  following works: -->

  <use xlink:href="#icon2" x="100" y="50" />


  <!--  why???? -->
```

Comment: Looks like its working to me :S (Chrome 39)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work. Your jsfiddle is not the same as your inline code (the x and y of the use are not the same).

If you make the x and y values in the `<g>` the same as outside it will work. In the non-working case you are clipping out the contents of the `<use>` with your clip-path.

Comment: Yeah! I think I accidentally solved it when i was trying to make my question more pretty. But why did the one got clipped out? I think the first clipPath makes the area, the (second) g element merges the image and the clip Path to one unit containing the desired. And this bundle is what i reference in use. But why does it get clipped of by a clip path  or end of svg element? I don't see where the clipper elements size is defined? Here is a fiddle showing the clipping of the second icon: http://jsfiddle.net/3dacnxdb/4/

Comment: The clip size is the rect within the clipPath element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see it because they are superposed... =)

```html
<svg id="graphic">
  <defs>

    <clipPath id="icon-cp">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="150" height="100" />
    </clipPath>

    <image id="icon-sprite" width="969" height="293" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPx5h.png" />

    <g id="icon2" clip-path="url(#icon-cp)">
      <use xlink:href="#icon-sprite" transform="translate(-240,0)" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <!--     ----------------------------------------
    Here is the question:
    
    the first use element is not displayed.
    The second one is displayed. (the elements are under this text)
    
    Why does it not work? How can a use element be used within nested g elements?

(to test it you can comment out the second use element, even tough both use elements have the same attributes no icon is visible anymore)
    ---------------------------------------- -->

  <!--  following does not work: -->
  <g id="testg">
    <use xlink:href="#icon2" x="0" y="0" />
  </g>

  <!--  following works: -->

  <use xlink:href="#icon2" x="100" y="50" />


  <!--  why???? -->
```